# User cannot be updated

Tags: mediawiki

I am using MediaWiki and I experience problem changing any user.

When I try to make a change, I got:

```
MWException from line 3484 of /something//includes/user/User.php: CAS update failed on user_touched. 
The version of the user to be saved is older than the current version.
```

Backtrace:

```
#0 /something//includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(4461): User->{closure}(Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqli, string)
#1 /something//includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(68): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->doAtomicSection(string, Closure)
#2 /something//includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(641): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->__call(string, array)
#3 /something//includes/user/User.php(3495): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->doAtomicSection(string, Closure)
#4 /something//includes/preferences/DefaultPreferencesFactory.php(1806): User->saveSettings()
#5 /something//includes/preferences/DefaultPreferencesFactory.php(1853): MediaWiki\Preferences\DefaultPreferencesFactory->saveFormData(array, PreferencesFormOOUI, array)
#6 /something//includes/preferences/DefaultPreferencesFactory.php(1687): MediaWiki\Preferences\DefaultPreferencesFactory->submitForm(array, PreferencesFormOOUI, array)
#7 /something//includes/htmlform/HTMLForm.php(707): MediaWiki\Preferences\DefaultPreferencesFactory->MediaWiki\Preferences\{closure}(array, PreferencesFormOOUI)
#8 /something//includes/htmlform/HTMLForm.php(597): HTMLForm->trySubmit()
#9 /something//includes/htmlform/HTMLForm.php(613): HTMLForm->tryAuthorizedSubmit()
#10 /something//includes/specials/SpecialPreferences.php(102): HTMLForm->show()
#11 /something//includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(600): SpecialPreferences->execute(NULL)
#12 /something//includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(635): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#13 /something//includes/MediaWiki.php(307): MediaWiki\SpecialPage\SpecialPageFactory->executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#14 /something//includes/MediaWiki.php(940): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#15 /something//includes/MediaWiki.php(543): MediaWiki->main()
#16 /something//index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#17 /something//index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#18 {main}
```

Log gives more info (but I dont see anything to worry about):

```
...
[UserOptionsManager] Loading options from database
[DBQuery] Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqlBase::serverIsReadOnly [0s] localhost: SELECT @@GLOBAL.read_only AS Value
[DBQuery] MediaWiki\User\UserOptionsManager::loadUserOptions [0s] localhost: SELECT up_property,up_value FROM `user_properties` WHERE up_user = 1
[DBQuery] Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqlBase::serverIsReadOnly [0.001s] localhost: SELECT @@GLOBAL.read_only AS Value
[DBQuery] MediaWiki\User\UserGroupManager::getUserGroupMemberships [0s] localhost: SELECT ug_user,ug_group,ug_expiry FROM `user_groups` WHERE ug_user = 1
[DBQuery] Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqlBase::serverIsReadOnly [0s] localhost: SELECT @@GLOBAL.read_only AS Value
[DBQuery] MediaWiki\User\UserGroupManager::getUserGroupMemberships [0s] localhost: SELECT ug_user,ug_group,ug_expiry FROM `user_groups` WHERE ug_user = 1
[Parser] Parser::setOutputFlag: set user-signature flag on 'Special:Preferences'; User signature detected
[DBQuery] Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqlBase::serverIsReadOnly [0.002s] localhost: SELECT @@GLOBAL.read_only AS Value
[preferences] Created form descriptor for user 'Admin'
[memcached] getWithSetCallback(global:rdbms-server-readonly:localhost:DB_NAME:): process cache hit
[DBQuery] Wikimedia\Rdbms\DatabaseMysqlBase::serverIsReadOnly [0.001s] localhost: SELECT @@GLOBAL.read_only AS Value
[DBQuery] startAtomic: entering level 0 (User::saveSettings)
[DBQuery] User::saveSettings [0s] localhost: UPDATE `user` SET user_name = 'Admin',user_real_name = '',user_email = '',user_email_authenticated = NULL,user_touched = '20210217095957',user_token = '0e49ef2817',user_email_token = NULL,user_email_token_expires = NULL WHERE user_id = 1 AND user_touched = '19700101003250'
[preferences] CAS update failed on user_touched for user ID '1' (master read)
[DBQuery] cancelAtomic: canceling level 0 (User::saveSettings)
[DBQuery] MWExceptionHandler::rollbackMasterChangesAndLog [0s] localhost: ROLLBACK
[DBQuery] Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database::ping [0.001s] localhost: SELECT 1 AS ping
```

Last MediaWiki. I updated it from 1.31 and before I couldn't update users too.

Any ideas, any hints? Anything would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The only strange thing is:
    user_touched = '19700101003250'

Comment: I dont have "LastUserLogin" extension which is notorious for this error.

Comment: You may want step by step: to upgrade by one major version only. Your problem can be relaed to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Actor_migration.